# An algorithm to split an area into multiple polygons based on other polygons intersection

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I have a list of `n` polygons `(A,B,C,D,E,...)` which possibly intersect each other.

I need to find a new list of polygons (or multi-polygons) which looks like this:

````
(
Area only in A (A difference from the rest)
Area only in B
Area only in C
...

Area only in A and B (A intersection with B and difference from the rest)
Area only in A and C
Area only in B and C
...

Area only in A,B and C (A intersection with B and C and difference from the rest)
Area only in A,B and D 
Area only in A,B and E 
....

)```

The only way I can find is to iterate all the combinations and run a simple intersection/difference algorithms but the number rapidly increases.
````

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. You tagged your question [tag:computational-geometry]: what did you find looking for ideas to *find polygon intersections with low effort*? How would you proceed if there were just *simple* polygons $A, B,$ and $C$? Does the problem get easier if [all edges are axis-aligned](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon)?

Comment: Are your polygons simple? If not, how do you define the interior area of a polygon? If your polygons are simple, it seems reasonable to first construct the planar subdivision, represented as a [DCEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list). Then, for each polygon, construct a list (or maybe adjacency graph?) with all faces of the subdivision contained in that polygon. Finally, use the lists to get the combined area of each of the intersections. While this approach doesn't seem very efficient yet, it seems there are some ways to make it better.